# Extract one class from global LULC in google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, land-cover, land-use

I am trying to extract one LULC class (e.g. cropland) for the entire globe from the MODIS global lulc. How it can be done?
Code I am using to display global lulc is:

```js
    var cover = ee.Image('MODIS/051/MCD12Q1/2012_01_01').select('Land_Cover_Type_1');
    var cover_palette = [
    'aec3d4', // water
    '152106', '225129', '369b47', '30eb5b', '387242', // forest
    '6a2325', 'c3aa69', 'b76031', 'd9903d', '91af40',  // shrub, grass
    '111149', // wetlands
    'cdb33b', // croplands
    'cc0013', // urban
    '33280d', // crop mosaic
    'd7cdcc', // snow and ice
    'f7e084', // barren
    '6f6f6f'  // tundra
     ];

    Map.addLayer(cover, {min: 0, max: 17, palette: cover_palette },  
                'Land Cover classification');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a lot of ways to do this. If you want to preserve class ID, you need to mask the desired class. For example:

```js
var crop_mask = cover.eq(13); // create a mask for crops
var crop = cover.mask(crop_mask); // mask it
Map.addLayer(crop,{},'Crops');
```

---

As Rodrigo E. Principe and Nicholas Clinton suggest:

```js
var crop = cover.updateMask(cover.eq(13)); // mask it
Map.addLayer(crop,{},'Crops');
```

Comment: I think you should use `upadteMask`, which will replace `mask` for applying a mask to an Image. Saludos =)

Comment: Good suggestion.  `updateMask()` is equivalent to `mask(newMask.and(image.mask())` which is preferable because you're not unmasking any pixels.

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe yes, you're right. Edited and thanks for the orientation

Comment: Thanks all of you. Is it possible to do this masking for several years. For example, I want to study the dynamics of cropland from 2005-2013 and I am trying to do that using:                                               
       var filtered = crop.filterDate('2001-01-01', '2012-01-01');
       Map.addLayer(filtered);  This is giving me an error saying crop.filterDate is not a function. How it can be resolved?

Comment: And while using the filterDate command in the starting just after select('Land_Cover_Type_1'); command; it is not giving me any temporal analysis though it is not giving any error.

Comment: Check your own code! You loaded an `image`, Is just one date. Load an `imageColletcion` prior to making a multi-temporal analysis